# replacing multiple tabs and with single tab in c# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text that I would like to format in a sensible way

```
"\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tEIMC\\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<!--<td valign=\"top\"><span class=\"HEAD\">EIMC<br>\\t</span></td>-->\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\tSavannah\t\t\t\t/ United States of America (UTC-5)\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t&nbsp;\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n645 Indian Street\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Savannah, GA 31401\t\t\t\tP.O. Box 1492 101-1001\t\t\t\t\\tSavannah, GA 31402\t\t\t\tUnited States of America\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPhone: +1 912 2342340\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tFax: +1 912 2310060\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tclwsurvey@aol.com\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tMr. Williams, Charles \t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tPrv. Phone: +1 912 2348458\t\t\t\tMobile: +1 912 6568884\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t&nbsp;&nbsp;\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t<!--printview-->\n\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t<!--printviewAnfang-->\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tMAP VIEW&nbsp;&nbsp;\t\t\t\tPRINT VIEW\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t<!--printviewEnde-->\n\t\t"
```

I have tried using the following regex expressions in C#.

```
var reg1 = Regex.Replace(node.InnerText, @"\t|\n|,|<!--(.*?)-->|(&nbsp.), " ");

var reg2 = Regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml, @"/\t+/|/\n+/|", "*");
```

the problem is that the multiple \t just get replaced by whitespaces, and I want to replace the multitude of \t with a single empty space, with the ultimate goal of making the whole thing exportable to csv while being somewhat readable.

Comment: updated the reflect the expected result. Its to get rid of all \t, \n and other html redundant data while keeping the actual information inside.

Comment: Do you really have literals `\t` in your string or is it just regulars tabulations?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
Regex.Replace(node.InnerText, @"(\\t|\\n|&nbsp;)+", "");
```

see <kbd>[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/mC0dA6/1)</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You can say:

```
result = Regex.Replace(node.InnerText, @"\t{2,}", @"\t");
```

This replaces multiple tabs to just one.

Comment: `"\t{2,}"` needs a `@`, doesn't it...?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub honestly I don't know for sure, since I am not very fluent in c#. Does it? Updating, thanks. In the meanwhile I am checking how the syntax works exactly.

Comment: @Thunderer I think that even removing multiple tabs the content will still be quite unreadable. I stored your string in a file in Linux, then `var=$(< file)` and then `echo -e "$var"`. It looks like a huge piece of HTML that needs other approaches to get cleaned properly.